# Django site running in Apache 2.4.6 on Centos giving 503 server error

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

Please assist. I have a Django site that i'm trying to configure to run in apache using mod_wsgi. I have setup my virtualhost as follows:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com

        Alias /static/my_site/ /opt/mysitepath/mysite/static/my_site/
        WSGIDaemonProcess my_site python-home=/usr/local/virtualenvironment python-path=/opt/mysitepath processes=2 threads=1
        WSGIProcessGroup my_site
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mysitepath/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=my_site
        <Directory /opt/mysitepath/mysite/static/my_site>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /opt/mysitepath/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog logs/mysite.com_log
</virtualhost>
```

The obvious issue i'm seeing when I startup apache is the following:

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
>   globally to suppress this message [Fri Apr 20 04:42:27.900968 2018]
>   [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1206] AH01757: generating secret for digest
>   authentication ... [Fri Apr 20 04:42:27.901742 2018]
>   [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1206] AH02282: No slotmem from
>   mod_heartmonitor [Fri Apr 20 04:42:27.997621 2018] [:warn] [pid 1206]
>   mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0. [Fri Apr 20 04:42:27.997647 2018]
>   [:warn] [pid 1206] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.5. [Fri Apr 20
>   04:42:27.997681 2018] [:alert] [pid 1206] (2)No such file or
>   directory: mod_wsgi (pid=1206): Couldn't bind unix domain socket
>   '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.1206.0.1.sock'. [Fri Apr 20 04:42:28.005204
>   2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1206] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
>   PHP/5.6.31 SVN/1.7.14 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.5 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations

And when I navigate to the website via the browser I get

> 503 Service unavailable

Any idea why apache can't bind on the socket where mod_wsgi should be listening? How can I get my site to load correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some formatting would help. Also your log file clearly says that the socket doesn't exists. Check that you have correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had to add an entry in my virtualhost

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

My virtual host now looks like the following:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<virtualhost *:80>

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com

        Alias /static/my_site/ /opt/mysitepath/mysite/static/my_site/
        WSGIDaemonProcess my_site python-home=/usr/local/virtualenvironment python-path=/opt/mysitepath processes=2 threads=1
        WSGIProcessGroup my_site
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/mysitepath/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=my_site
        <Directory /opt/mysitepath/mysite/static/my_site>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /opt/mysitepath/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog logs/mysite.com_log
</virtualhost>
```